# в библиотеке lxml нет xpath

Tags: python, xml, lxml

использую python3.10.4

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import lxml
from lxml import etree

file = "123.xml"

parser = etree.XMLParser(
    encoding='utf-8',
    recover=True,
)

root = etree.fromstring(file.encode(), parser=parser)
address = root.xpath('.//row')[0].get('ip')

for i in address:
    print(i)
```

но при запуске получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "123456.py", line 13, in <module>
    address = root.xpath('.//row')[0].get('ip')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'xpath'
```

Comment: в библиотеке все есть. а вот ваш объект - пустой. об этом вам ошибка и говорит (NoneType)

Comment: и как исправить это?

Comment: xpath не нашел './/row', так понятно?

Answer (score 1):

В коде ошибка в том, что Вы разбираете в XML не содержимое файла, а строчку "123.xml", посмотрите документаицю по lxml. Вот короткий рабочий пример:

```
from lxml import etree

xml = '''<X><row ip="123"/></X>'''
root = etree.fromstring(xml)
print(root.xpath('.//row')[0].get('ip'))
```